# where is my mistake in my SQL code?

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

SQL Command :

```
UPDATE table1
SET colOne=1
WHERE id EXISTS (
SELECT IF(col1=19,col2,col1) AS id
FROM table2 
WHERE
(col3=19 AND col4='X') 
OR 
(col3=0 AND col4='Y' AND (col1=19 OR col2=19))
)
```

the inner `SELECT` query separately work fine

Comment: what is incorrect with your query?

Comment: I dont know but it not work and have an Error near EXISTS

Comment: try to replace `EXISTS`  with `IN`

Comment: @Alex Tank you it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1
SET colOne=1
WHERE id IN (
SELECT IF(col1=19,col2,col1) AS id
FROM table2 
WHERE
(col3=19 AND col4='X') 
OR 
(col3=0 AND col4='Y' AND (col1=19 OR col2=19))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use = instead of exists

```
UPDATE table1
SET colOne=1
WHERE id = (
SELECT IF(col1=19,col2,col1) AS id
FROM table2 
WHERE
(col3=19 AND col4='X') 
OR 
(col3=0 AND col4='Y' AND (col1=19 OR col2=19))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this

```
UPDATE table1
SET colOne=1
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT IF(col1=19,col2,col1) AS id
FROM table2 
WHERE
(col3=19 AND col4='X') 
OR 
(col3=0 AND col4='Y' AND (col1=19 OR col2=19))
)
```